# Whet using colcon, I get an error "No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath' "

Tags: python-3.x, ros

I'm using colcon for creating ROS2 package. And I can't build any package because of error "No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'"

when i do `colcon build` command, the terminal says next:
`Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

I've already tried update numpy
`pip install numpy --upgrade`

It didn't help(

Answer (score 0):

can you show your full terminal output?
you can also try with `colcon ignore` for the location you have got error and the `colcon build`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).